# What is the figurative meaning of "side dish"?

Tags: meaning

I know what a side dish is, but I can't figure out its figurative meaning. Can you please give a definition to it.

> The daily Beast started as an aggregator with some original reporting as a **side dish**.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A side dish accompanies the main part of a meal, making it complete. But the primary focus is not on the side dish.

The figurative meaning is the same - something that is a part of the whole package, but of lesser importance.

Another frequently used metaphor would be a supporting actor.

Answer (score 2):

A side dish can also be a person you're seeing intimately outside of your primary monogamous romantic relationship.

I'm having a hard time finding this definition anywhere other than [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sidedish) at the moment.

Comment: While technically true, the reason you are having trouble finding this definition outside of Urban Dictionary is that this is really informal and somewhat 'new' slang.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn no argument on it being really informal, but it's not new. When I saw the title in HNQ, I actually thought the question was going to be about this usage; was surprised to see it wasn't.

Comment: And not a good fit in the given context, unless you want to insinuate that the website has a second business model.

Comment: @Stephie haha definitely true, just added for completeness (someone finding _that_ context may do a search and end up on this question as well)

Comment: I've seen this (in very informal slang) referred to as a "side piece"/"side chick", never a "side dish".

Comment: @V2Blast I've heard the other 2 as well, and I'd say side piece is the most common of the 3